# Javascript If statement not working in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have the following Javascript code that works perfectly as far as the autocompleting as well as filling 5 additional input fields, based on the loaded array from MySQL in the type_code.php file.

The sixth element of the array val(names[6]) is filled with a database value of either Yes or No and I am trying to use this value to control whether an additional form field becomes readonly or readwrite at the front end.

It seems as if my if statement is badly formatted, as if I run the two lines of codes without the if everything works as expected.

```
        // Autocomplete Invoice To from Code and sets ReadOnly/ReadWrite based on Editable field in Code record
        $('#add_at_inv2_code1').autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'type_code.php',
                    dataType: "json", 
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        name_startsWith: request.term,
                        type: 'code_table',
                        row_num : 1
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            var code = item.split("|");
                            return {
                                label: code[0],
                                value: code[0],
                                data : item
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });

            },
            autoFocus: true,              
            minLength: 0,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
                $('#desc_at_inv2_code1').val(names[1]);
                $('#add_at_inv2_code2').val(names[2]);
                $('#add_at_inv2_client').val(names[3]);
                $('#add_at_salesrep').val(names[4]);
                $('#add_at_category').val(names[5]);

                // Code that is not working
                if($(val(names[6])) == "Yes") {
                $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('readonly',false);
                $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('disabled',false);
                } else {
                $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('readonly',true);
                $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('disabled',true);
                }

            }               
        });
```

Can someone please help me structure this if statement correctly?

Thanks,
Adri

Comment: why are you using $(val(names[6])) simply use names[6]=="Yes". Try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The val() method returns or sets the value attribute of the selected elements.**

**Note: The val() method is mostly used with HTML form elements.**

Use

```
if(names[6] == "Yes")
```

instead of

```
if($(val(names[6])) == "Yes")
```

=========================================================================

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Autocomplete Invoice To from Code and sets ReadOnly/ReadWrite based on Editable field in Code record
            $('#add_at_inv2_code1').autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'type_code.php',
                        dataType: "json", 
                        method: 'post',
                        data: {
                            name_startsWith: request.term,
                            type: 'code_table',
                            row_num : 1
                        },
                        success: function( data ) {
                            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                var code = item.split("|");
                                return {
                                    label: code[0],
                                    value: code[0],
                                    data : item
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });

                },
                autoFocus: true,              
                minLength: 0,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
                    $('#desc_at_inv2_code1').val(names[1]);
                    $('#add_at_inv2_code2').val(names[2]);
                    $('#add_at_inv2_client').val(names[3]);
                    $('#add_at_salesrep').val(names[4]);
                    $('#add_at_category').val(names[5]);

                    // Code that is not working
                    if(names[6] == "Yes") {
                        $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('readonly',false);
                        $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('disabled',false);
                    } else {
                        $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('readonly',true);
                        $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('disabled',true);
                    }

                }               
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation here too

Comment: @Akintunde yes. updataded my answer. thank you for suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Need following change in your code
// Code that is not working
if(names[6] == "Yes") //Change this if($(val(names[6])) == "Yes")
{
   $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('readonly',false);
   $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('disabled',false);
}
else
{
   $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('readonly',true);
   $('#add_at_inv2_client').prop('disabled',true);
}
```